# GeoJSON not saving in Einstein Analytics

Tags: einstein-analytics

My Einstein Analytics GeoJSON will not save and no error is thrown.  No results are posted to the page.

[image: GeoJSON Config]

Answer (score 1):

In order to save GeoJSON, you must not use any spaces in the GeoJSON name.  This is the equivalent of the API Name of the GeoJSON and would follow rules similar to other API Name fields on the platform.

[image: Einstein analytics GeoJSON]